# python encoding problem with mysqldb

Tags: python, encoding, mysql-python

I have troubles with encoding in python while using `xlrd` and `mysqldb`.
I am reading an excel file which contains Turkish characters in it.

When I print the value like that `print sheet.cell(rownum,19).value` it writes `İstanbul` to console, which is correct.(Win7 Lucida ConsoleLine,encoding is `cp1254)

However, if I want to insert that value to database like

```
sql = "INSERT INTO city (name) VALUES('"+sheet.cell(rownum,19).value+"')"
cursor.execute (sql)
db.commit()
```

gives error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "excel_employer.py", line 112, in <module> cursor.execute (sql_deneme)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 157, in execute
    query = query.encode(charset)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u0130' in position
    41: ordinal not in range(256)
```

If I change the sql as

```
sql = "INSERT INTO city (name) VALUES('"+sheet.cell(rownum,19).value.encode('utf8')+"')"
```

the value is inserted without any error but it becomes `Ä°stanbul`

Could you give me any idea how can I put the value `İstanbul` to database as it is.

Comment: I agree but is this totally about MySQL ?

Comment: I don't know what `xlrd` is, but my guess is that the problem is on MySQL's side. If someone more knowledgeable hasn't answered you by tonight when I get home maybe I can look up some code I have and actually give an answer of some sort.

Comment: I really need any help urgently !

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked with this since last summer, when I had a nightmare with it. Looking more closely, I am convinced your problem is with MySQL, not with xlrd. Are you settings the `use_unicode` on your connection? I'm suspecting you are. That's good. But you also have to set MySQL's internal encoding to UTF-8 for it to actually work right. Sorry got to run right now but see if you can find anything on that.

Answer (score 1):

Just as @Kazark said, maybe the encoding of your connector of mysql is not set.

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root",
    port=3306,
    db="test1",
    init_command="set names utf8"
    )
```

Try this, when you init your python connector of mysql. But be sure the content been inserted is utf-8.